# get list of files edited and type of edit using git

Tags: git

is there a way to get a list of all files that have been edited in a commit using git?
the info I would need are:

```
file1 edited 
file2 deleted 
file3 edited
file4 created
```

I tried
`git show <sha>`
but gives info about all the changes at line level, does something exist for files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
git show --name-status the-commit-id
```